# How to automatically create Activity related material in an Android Library?

Tags: android, android-studio

The new module creation interface of Android Studio for Android Library only creates empty folders. How can I automatically create a similar setup as if I created a Basic Activity setup?

Right clicking on package name>New Activity>Basic Activity is greyed out. It says ***No application theme found***.

I see two ways to accomplish this.

1. Do everything by hand - create styles.xml, modify manifest.xml, etc.?
2. Create an Android phone/tablet module and then change the plugin to library and remove applicationId.

I want to know if there's an official way of creating Android Library that goes beyond creating empty folders?

Thanks.

Comment: "Right clicking..." -- that feels like a bug in Android Studio.

Comment: @CommonsWare there's no theme defined in manifest.xml and there's is no styles.xml. So a lot of Activities can't be created via GUI. Do you think that's a bug?

Comment: "there's no theme defined in manifest.xml and there's is no styles.xml" -- you do not need either of those to have an activity. You need them to have a subclass of `AppCompatActivity`, but not `Activity`. "Do you think that's a bug?" -- IMHO, it is a bug. Whether *Google* would consider it a bug is another matter entirely. Personally, I'd go with Gabe's solution and avoid the new-activity wizards entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do it by hand-  all you need to do is create a new class that extends from Activity, and add the Activity to the manifest.  Everything else is extraneous.  You've probably already spent more time trying to make the tool work than you would writing your first hundred activities.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to avoid having to write styles.xml, modify manifest.xml, etc. I will probably end up forgetting something to add there.